# ifstream istream and >> overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, polymorphism

I'm sure this is a simple issue, but I am having trouble solving it:

I receive this from the compiler:

```
cdcheck.cpp|31|error: 'slectionsIn' was not declared in this scope
```

the offending blocks of code:

in main:

```
...snip
ifstream selectionsIn (argv[2]);
PlayListItem item;
int itemCount = 0;
while (slectionsIn >> item)
{
...snip
```

in PlayListItem.cpp:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, PlayListItem& pl){
```

I can post the contents of these files if needed.  It should be noted that this compiles correctly if I change from istream to ifstream in the declaration, but I can not modify PlayListItem.cpp, only main.

Comment: Check your spelling: `selectionsIn` or `slectionsIn`?

Answer (score 3):

Try fixing the misspelled identifier that was mentioned in the compiler error message:

```
while (selectionsIn >> item) // not: slectionsIn
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare

`ifstream` **`selectionsIn`**`(argv[2]);`

to

`while (`**`slectionsIn`** `>> item)`